# how to add multiple newsletter in one page with magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I want to add two newsletter in my site.One is in the footer and another one when i hover the topmenu.
I tried to add two newsletter in my page and it also worked but the problem is if i am adding another newsletter in my site then first newsletter is not working.I donot know what is the problem.
If anyone knows this, please help me out.
Thanks!
I put subscribe_footer.phtml in `\app\design\frontend\default\mytheme\template\newsletter`

```
<div class="row-7-col-1">
                        <h2><?php echo $this->__('newsletter') ?></h2>  
                        <p><?php echo $this->__('Sign up to our newsletter and get exclusive deals you wont find anywhere else straight to your inbox!') ?></p>
                <form action="<?php echo $this->getFormActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="newsletter-footer-validate-detail-footer">

             <input type="text" name="email" id="newsletter-footer" title="<?php echo $this->__('Sign up for our newsletter') ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" />


          <input type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?>" class="newsbtn" value="submit">
          </form></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
 var newsletterSubscriberFormDetail = new VarienForm('newsletter-footer-validate-detail-footer');
    //]]>
    </script>
</div>
```

For another newsletter,I put subscribe.phtml in `\app\design\frontend\default\mytheme\template\newsletter`

```
<div class="row-7-col-1">
                        <h2><?php echo $this->__('newsletter') ?></h2>  
                        <p><?php echo $this->__('Sign up to our newsletter and get exclusive deals you wont find anywhere else straight to your inbox!') ?></p>
                 <form action="<?php echo $this->getFormActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="newsletter-validate-detail">

             <input type="text" name="email"  id="newsletter"  class="field required-entry validate-email"/>


          <input type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?>" class="newsbtn" value="submit">
          </form></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var newsletterSubscriberFormDetail = new VarienForm('newsletter-validate-detail');
    //]]>
    </script>
</div>
```

please check and tell me why only one newsletter validation is working

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="block block-subscribe">
<form action="<?php echo $this->getFormActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="newsletter-validate-detail_footer">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter email" id="email_footer" class="input-text required-entry validate-email mytxt2" />
    <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Subscribe') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Subscribe') ?></span></span></button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var newsletterSubscriberFormDetail_footer = new VarienForm('newsletter-validate-detail_footer');
    //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: two newsletter is coming but validation is not working for other newsletter

Comment: Hey Kumar, change the form elements attribute values from the first newsletter form elements as i mentioned above. If you do it right validation should also work. show me the website where you are trying to implement.

Comment: I am writing the code of two p[ages above you please check that

Comment: Check my modified answer that is how i implement two newsletter form on the same page. you can also check live example here http://chicfest.ca/

Comment: still it is not working can you please edit my two newsletter coding briefly as i posted above please.because my validation is not working for 1 newsletter

Comment: Hey Kumar, Please check other JavaScript code on your site which may conflict with other js. I just copy and paste your above code in my subscribe.phtml files on my local server and I also amazed that they are working perfectly without any problem validation also are working on both of them.

Comment: can you tell me what you have written in newsletter.xml for both newsletter

Comment: will you please write each and every step for adding two newsletter means what you have written in .phtml page and .xml page please explain from starting

Answer (score -1):

Two Newsletters are working as well as validation also worked for me.
Copy the `newsletter/subscribe` file and rename to `newsletter/subscribe2`.
Then just rename the validation name on newsletter.